# How to Bind a Combo Box back color to a Panel back color in C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visual-studio, winforms

So... I am trying to program a little game in C# (mastermind), and i got 4 different panels and 4 different combo boxes and for example i want Pane1 to have the same back color as the choosen Color in ComboBox1. right now i did it with a list but i would like to know if there is a better / shorter way to do this.

```
        private void Suggestion_Box_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ComboBox> boxes = new List<ComboBox>()
        {
            Suggestion_Box1,
            Suggestion_Box2,
            Suggestion_Box3,
            Suggestion_Box4
        };
        var i = 0;
        foreach (ComboBox cb in boxes)
        {
            if (cb.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                cb.BackColor = Color.FromName(All_Colors[cb.SelectedIndex]);
                Suggestion_Panel1.BackColor = Suggestion_Box1.BackColor;
                Suggestion_Panel2.BackColor = Suggestion_Box2.BackColor;
                Suggestion_Panel3.BackColor = Suggestion_Box3.BackColor;
                Suggestion_Panel4.BackColor = Suggestion_Box4.BackColor;  
            }
        }
    }
```

The "All_Colors" array is a string array with different colors in it.
The Suggestion Boxes are Combo Boxes
and the Suggestion Panel are Panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion, no need to update all the panels' back color when only 1 should be changed. You can bind each panel's BackColor property to corresponding ComboBox's BackColor property.

My code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> colors = new List<string> { "red", "blue", "green", "yellow" };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // binding here
        this.panel1.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", this.comboBox1, "BackColor");
        this.panel2.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", this.comboBox2, "BackColor");
        this.panel3.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", this.comboBox3, "BackColor");
        this.panel4.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", this.comboBox4, "BackColor");
    }

    private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        if(comboBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
            return;
        comboBox.BackColor = Color.FromName(colors[comboBox.SelectedIndex]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah thanks for your post, but i think i got a good way to do this :D.

Comment: This a good way, but a couple of notes: 1. You could have a `List<Color>` and use it as the `ComboBox.DataSource` (the `Color` name will be used as the `DisplayMember` automatically), then, in the `SelectedIndexChanged` handler, you can set `comboBox.BackColor = (Color)comboBox.SelectedItem;`. 2. always add a check for an index `< 0`, as in `if (comboBox.SelectedIndex < 0) return;`

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself, i do not know if its the best thing to do, but i did it like this.

```
        private void Suggestion_Box_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<ComboBox, Panel> CoLi = new Dictionary<ComboBox, Panel>
        {
            { Suggestion_Box1, Suggestion_Panel1 },
            { Suggestion_Box2, Suggestion_Panel2 },
            { Suggestion_Box3, Suggestion_Panel3 },
            { Suggestion_Box4, Suggestion_Panel4 }
        };
        foreach (var i in CoLi)
        {
            if (i.Key.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                i.Key.BackColor = Color.FromName(Used_Colors[i.Key.SelectedIndex]);
                i.Value.BackColor = Color.FromName(Used_Colors[i.Key.SelectedIndex]);
            }
        }
    }
```